# Google API optimizeTours: does not returns optimized route

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using Google API and method optimizeTours to optimize vehicle route.

API: https://cloudoptimization.googleapis.com/v1/projects/MY API PROJECT:optimizeTours

This is my request

```json
{
    "model": {
        "shipments": [
            {
                "label": "987",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.2034733,
                            "longitude": -78.49189695
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "983",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.20334675,
                            "longitude": -78.490163733333
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "957",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.20329959035475,
                            "longitude": -78.489062200445
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "935",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.20290136666667,
                            "longitude": -78.490132566667
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "690",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.2002005,
                            "longitude": -78.4924999
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "910",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.20324258333333,
                            "longitude": -78.49150005
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "729",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.19757333333333,
                            "longitude": -78.481011666667
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "719",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.19855,
                            "longitude": -78.485678333333
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "720",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.19947166666667,
                            "longitude": -78.486215
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "721",
                "deliveries": [
                    {
                        "arrivalLocation": {
                            "latitude": -0.19409166666667,
                            "longitude": -78.491781666667
                        },
                        "duration": "300s",
                        "timeWindows": [
                            {
                                "startTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
                                "endTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "vehicles": [
            {
                "loadLimits": {
                    "weight": {
                        "maxLoad": 5000
                    }
                },
                "startLocation": {
                    "latitude": -0.192298,
                    "longitude": -78.4877
                },
                "endLocation": {
                    "latitude": -0.192298,
                    "longitude": -78.4877
                }
            }
        ],
        "globalStartTime": "2023-10-21T07:00:00-05:00",
        "globalEndTime": "2023-10-21T17:00:00-05:00"
    }
}
```

and this is my response:

```json
{
    "routes": [
        {
            "vehicleStartTime": "2023-10-21T12:00:00Z",
            "vehicleEndTime": "2023-10-21T13:36:13Z",
            "visits": [
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 9,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T12:03:26Z",
                    "detour": "0s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "721"
                },
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 8,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T12:14:23Z",
                    "detour": "581s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "720"
                },
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 7,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T12:23:57Z",
                    "detour": "1116s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "719"
                },
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 6,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T12:31:52Z",
                    "detour": "1557s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "729"
                },
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 5,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T12:43:53Z",
                    "detour": "2214s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "910"
                },
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 4,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T12:52:41Z",
                    "detour": "2831s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "690"
                },
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 3,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T13:03:45Z",
                    "detour": "3394s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "935"
                },
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 2,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T13:09:54Z",
                    "detour": "3773s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "957"
                },
                {
                    "shipmentIndex": 1,
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T13:16:37Z",
                    "detour": "4215s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "983"
                },
                {
                    "startTime": "2023-10-21T13:24:04Z",
                    "detour": "4676s",
                    "shipmentLabel": "987"
                }
            ],
            "vehicleDetour": "5773s"
        }
    ],
    "metrics": {
        "aggregatedRouteMetrics": {
            "performedShipmentCount": 10,
            "travelDuration": "2773s",
            "waitDuration": "0s",
            "delayDuration": "0s",
            "breakDuration": "0s",
            "visitDuration": "3000s",
            "totalDuration": "5773s",
            "travelDistanceMeters": 11105
        },
        "usedVehicleCount": 1,
        "earliestVehicleStartTime": "2023-10-21T12:00:00Z",
        "latestVehicleEndTime": "2023-10-21T13:36:13Z"
    }
}
```

It just returned shipments by decreasing order of `shipmentIndex` and does not do optimization.
Also I tried to send request of 60 shipments and in response appears same things: shipments just returned with decreased index of shipment 59 58 57 56 55 54 and so on until 1.

What should I do to make response return optimized routes?